# Load more content with jquery & php

Tags: javascript, php, jquery, ajax, load

I'm trying to create a "load more" button to the news section of my website, but whenever I try anything my mind goes blank and I don't know how to begin making it.
I'm not good at any javascript/jquery/ajax just "some" php.

So far I only have my php script display all the news from my database...

```
$sql = mysqli_query($con,"SELECT * FROM news ORDER BY date DESC") 
or die     (mysql_error());
while($row = mysqli_fetch_array($sql)){
$usql = mysqli_query($con,"SELECT * FROM members WHERE id = 1");
while($user = mysqli_fetch_array($usql)){
    echo('<li class=""><br/>('.$row['date'].')');
    echo ('<a href="/news/'.$row['id'].'" title="'.$user['username'].'" rel="nofollow">');
    echo ('<img src="'.$row['img'].'" alt="'.$user['username'].'" class="list_intros_img">');
    echo ('<h4><a href="/news/'.$row['id'].'" title="'.$user['username'].'">'.$row['title'].'</a></h4>');
    echo ('<p>'.substr($row['content'],0,400).'</p>');
    echo ('</li><hr class="line">');
}
}
```

Comment: Commonly referred to as [infinite scroll](http://www.jquery4u.com/tutorials/jquery-infinite-scrolling-demos/)

Comment: Just php you're joking :) 1. cool formatting, 2.why using fetch_array if you're not even using it? 3. doing 2 queries where you have to do only one? 4. what is 'my mind' goes blank? So you want to program? First of all learn by some tutorials, then construct in your head and then create it. 5. begin with google.com, any other advices you would not get, if your question is not: do it for me, cuz my mind goes blank ^^ Btw. LIMIT 10, on click LIMIT 10,20.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I suggest you to load a default number of news when you first load the page, map the "load more" button with an ajax request to fetch more news and update your list.

You could use the LIMIT and OFFSET keyword in MySQL to fetch more news. (https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.0/en/select.html).
In your case, that could be something like : "SELECT * FROM news ORDER BY date DESC LIMIT 10 OFFSET 10" to display news 11 to 20.

I hope this gives you a lead to get started.